# Prepopulate form with it's instance if invalid using CreateView Django

Tags: python, django

I use generic CreateView to create a User instance.

```
class SignUp(CreateView):

    template_name = 'reg.html'
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):

        raw_password = form.instance.password
        form.instance.set_password(raw_password)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How would I efficiently prepopulate form with it's own instance if any form error occurs? Without rewriting `post` methods or smth if possible. Thanks.